# Find the splitting field of a polynomial over $Z_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

this question is from the book Graduate Algebra written by Lang.

It asks me to find the splitting field of $f(x)=x^{p^{8}} -1$ over the field $Z_{p}$.

I got a proof from my friend but I don't really understand it.

So the proof is:

Notice that $x^{p^{8}} -1 = (x-1)^{p^{8}}$ in $Z_{p}$, so we can linearly factor f(x) into $(x-1)^{p^{8}}$ and all the $1$ in the linear factors are in $Z_{p}$, so $Z_{p}$ is the splitting field.

I understand the second half part of the proof, since it is the definition of the splitting field, but why could I get $x^{p^{8}} -1 = (x-1)^{p^{8}}$ in $Z_{p}$.

If the proof is not correct, could you give me some hints or detailed proofs?

Thank you!

Comment: The "notice that" is false: $\;p^8\neq 8p\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I am sorry that I gave the wrong proof, I will edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was incorrect...but close:

$$x^{p^8}-1=\left(x^p-1\right)^{p^7}\;\ldots$$

Comment: But why can I factor in this way?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Because you're working in characteristic $\;p\;$ and thus we have the Freshman's Dream: $\;(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p\;$

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I forgot this.